# VS code source control populates with all the files (code and zip files) from my User folder on Mac

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

At the moment my VScode, source control tab shows 5K file changed (unstated commits). I ran

```
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
```

and prints

```
/User/myName
```

so I go that location where I have a git folder but it only contains 2 of my previous projects I cloned from before hand with HTTPS.

Opening a new vscode window doesn't work either and vs code is up to date.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your home directory is a Git repository. Git will try to look up the directory hierarchy until it finds a `.git` directory, and the first place it finds one, it will consider that its repository.

If you don't want Visual Studio Code to consider that the repository for your project, then you either need to disable the source control functionality for what you're working on, or create a repository for your project by running `git init` in the top-level directory of your project (and possibly restarting VS Code). Once Git sees the new repository, it won't recurse up to your home folder anymore.

As an alternative, you could also not have your home directory be a repository. If you manage your dotfiles using Git, you could have a script to copy them from the repository into your home directory instead of having your home directory as a repository.

Comment: I have the same problem, but even when the code is in it's own git repo VS Code still recurses up the tree to my home folder.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm currently a student in college but I had the same issue. At some point I had created a repository in my users directory. What I did to fix it is I deleted the .git folder in my users directory.

First be sure to make sure you can see hidden files.
Then scroll to the .git folder and right click delete.
Then VSCode no longer recognized users as a repository